# 24 hours format hrs and min with leading zeros

Tags: javascript

Looking for 24 hours format,  hours + min string
for ex :

2:05 AM => 0205  ( need to add leading zero)
4:30 PM => 1030

hours & min should be 4 digit always, thanks for your help.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: Try out http://momentjs.com/
Nice js framework for dealing with dates.

Comment: `4:30 PM => 1030` I'd be amazed if http://momentjs.com/ could do that.

Comment: thanks for your reply, how i can do that in javascript , sorry i forgot to mention that , looking for above conversion using javascript code

Answer (score 0):

created below logic..

```
var d = new Date();
    var sHours = d.getHours();
    var sMinutes = d.getMinutes();
    if (sHours < 10) sHours = "0" + sHours;
    if (sMinutes < 10) sMinutes = "0" + sMinutes;
    var seq_no = sHours + "" + sMinutes;
```